# Mail Merge using the Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml, mailmerge

I have a DataTable with 3 columns (a,b,c) and a docx file with the corresponding MailMerge fields set up. What I'd like to do is perform a Mail Merge on the document with the data.

Presume that you can write to the hard disk (if you need to create a csv etc for doing the merge etc), you *don't* have word, excel etc, Open XML SDK *is* installed, but equally we can install anything else.

In terms of the answer, converting the input data to whatever is needed isn't really a problem, the problem is *how* to perform a mail merge in the Open XML SDK (or other FREE API).

As a side note, the output should be one file with n pages (where n is the number of rows in the data), i.e. not n documents (though I don't mind if the merge of documents is done at the end).

(I should add, I'm not tied to the MailMerge concept, being able to just do a replace for example would work - though obviously that then requires merging the files together at the end...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working in a pretty horrible way - basically - at the moment, the algorithm follows this:

1. Unzip docx file
2. Read in document.xml (to a string)
3. string.Replace the fields
4. Rezip to temporary docx
5. Merge all the temporary documents created

The actual code for merging the documents comes from Eric White's Blog : http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2009/02/05/move-insert-delete-paragraphs-in-word-processing-documents-using-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx